# MSI and pinned shortcuts by software upgrades

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a question regarding advertised shortcuts, even when I think it is not possible.

When I create a new app version (path and exe have the same name) I also create a new MSI package with WIX. Same upgrade code, new product code. Unfortunately pinned shortcuts will disappear because the product code changes even if the path is correct and still the same. Is there a way to use an advertised shortcut, pin it and keep it after version upgrades even if the product code of the MSI has changed?

The way I create the shortcut:

```
<Component Id="test2" Guid="B598A884-7400-44E4-A8F0-51D08E0008BD">
                <File Id="test.wpf.exe" Name="test.wpf.exe" Source="$(var.test.wpf.TargetDir)\test.wpf.exe" KeyPath="yes" />
                <Shortcut Id="Shortcut_Test"
                    Directory="ProgramMenuFolder"
                    Name="Test"
                    WorkingDirectory="INSTALLDIR"
                    Advertise="yes"
                    Icon="test.wpf.exe"
                    IconIndex="0"
                    Show="normal"
                />
            </Component>
```

Thanks
Stephan

Comment: No time to look at this, but I found this in my bookmarks: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=26249 - I think Libre Office might preserve pinned shortcuts during upgrades, but I am not 100% sure. Maybe you can test and have a look what they do? [Here is another thread on the issue](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/issues/6297). You have probably found all this already, but let me just add it in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the comment from Stein Asmul but it did not lead to a solution.

The only way I figured out is to keep the same Product Code ID and also the same Component ID where the shortcut is referenced to.